# Misfired Simple triggers are executing Jobs in spite of Setting misfire policy to "IGNORE"

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz

I am using Quartz in .Net.
    Irrespective of "quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" i set and setting misfire policy to ignore, still i see job getting executed.

Ideally this should never happen.

I have initialized both JobListener and Trigger listeners for the same
Here is my snippet

```
 var props = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" },
                {"quartz.threadPool.threadCount","1" },
                {"quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold","3000" }
            };
            var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);

            // get a scheduler
            var scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
            //scheduler.CheckExists()
            await scheduler.Start();

 var job3 = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                .WithIdentity("myJob3", "group3")
                .UsingJobData("jobSays", "Hello World 333333")
                .UsingJobData("myFloatValue", 9.423f)
                .Build();
 var trigger3  = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group3")
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
                .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                .Build();

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job3, trigger3);
```

Comment: Not familiar with Quartz but could it be that WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires has to called after WithSimpleSchedule and not in it as a Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()` fires all triggers that were missed as soon as possible and then goes back to ordinary schedule. You should use `.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()`, trigger with explicitly set "MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING" misfire instruction handler, meaning that all misfired executions are discarded, it simply waits for next scheduled time. A misfire occurs if a trigger "misses" its firing time because there are no available threads in Quartz’s thread pool for executing the job

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really tough to make this out from Quartz documentation.